# Is there a simple way to serialize/deserialize a collection of entities from an EF container?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization, xml-serialization

The following sequence of events seems to crop up for me:

1. I create a model.
2. I load data into the model.
3. I change the model, losing the data in the round trip.
4. I reload data into the model, writing alot of boilerplate code to do so.

Options I can think of:

- (A) have SSMS generate scripts before I change the model.
- (B) using
  TSQL for xml feature to get my data into XML (I'd have to learn how
  to do this but it seems possible).
- (C) alter the EF code generation
  to place XML serialization attributes
- (D) have an
  expert tell me why my approach is wrong and set me straight so this
  problem is nullified

Answer (score 0):

Once you have serialized and shared/stored that data, you essentially have a contract. Therefore, if you foresee any issues of versioning the model, I would create a **separate** DTO model for serialization purposes. Then you can reload the data into your DTO even if your DB model changes. You will obviously need to map the DB model to/from the DB model, but that is usually pretty trivial.

In short, I think the problem is the dual use of the model:

```
DB <===> Model <==> storage
```

When the following works better:

```
DB <===> DB Model <==*==> DTO Model <===> storage
```

Now you can handle versioning the DB Model separately, by tweaking the code you have in the link marked `*`

You can *also* handle storage changes in this scenario, or even support multiple DTO models (either for different purposes, or different/incompatible revisions).

Whenever serialization gets tricky, the simplest fix is usually: introduce a DTO